# How to hide play bar and title for flex video in foundation 5

Tags: apache-flex, video, hide, zurb-foundation, toolbar

I'm trying to remove the bottom bar and title bar and just have the play button in the middle of the video so it appears nicer on mobile phones. I'm curious as to if anyone has found a way to do this with foundation or any alternative solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to just use a Youtube iFrame because I couldn't get the Flex Video to work.

Here's a list of embedded player parameters for Youtube as well. Unsure whether or not this will work with the flex video player because there could be other things blocking it but I decided to just use iFrame.

Youtube Parameters:  https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

`<iframe width="560" height="349" src="YOUR_VIDEO_HERE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Answer (score 1):

Flex video is just a responsive container around the video, it can't change the presentation of the video itself.  The way you did it (using the youtube iframe parameters) is the right way as far as I know.

Now you can toss a

```
<div class='flex-video widescreen'>
</div>
```

Or some such, around your video and it will scale properly across devices.